# How to display specific content in WooCommerce product subcategories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I'm using code that needs to display specific content on different category pages.

My categories have the following structure:

Man

- Cloth
- - Shorts
- - - Shorts with pockets

But the code below, displays content only on the parent category (Man), and the 1st level subcategory (Cloth):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'add_slide_text',1 );
function add_slide_text() {
    $cat = get_queried_object();

    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        if ( is_product_category( 'man' ) ||  $cat->parent === 233 ) {
            echo 'Hello man';
        } elseif ( is_product_category( 'woman' ) ||  $cat->parent === 232 ) {
            echo 'Hello woman';
        } else {
            echo '';
        }
    }
}
```

How can I force it to display content on subcategories of a lower level? For example, in "Shorts" and "Shorts with pockets" *(and possibly lower)*?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_term_children()` WordPress function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_children/) with WooCommerce product category custom taxonomy, to display a specific text from for each specific product category "man" and "woman" terms and their children as follows:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'add_slide_text', 1 );
function add_slide_text() {
    // Targeting WooCommerce product category archives
    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        $current_term = get_queried_object();
        $taxonomy     = $current_term->taxonomy;

        // For "man" term (and term ID 233)
        $term_man_id      = get_term_by('slug', 'man', $taxonomy)->term_id; // Get "man" term ID
        $children_man_ids = (array) get_term_children($term_man_id, $taxonomy); // Get children terms IDs
        $man_terms_ids    = array_merge( array(233, $term_man_id), $children_man_ids ); // Merge terms IDs in a unique array

        // For "woman" term (and term ID 232)
        $term_woman_id      = get_term_by('slug', 'woman', $taxonomy)->term_id; // Get "woman" term ID
        $children_woman_ids = (array) get_term_children($term_woman_id, $taxonomy); // Get children terms IDs
        $woman_terms_ids    = array_merge( array(232, $term_woman_id), $children_woman_ids ); // Merge terms IDs in a unique array

        // Conditional text display
        if ( in_array( $current_term->term_id, $man_terms_ids ) ) {
            _e('Hello man', 'woocommerce');
        } 
        elseif ( in_array( $current_term->term_id, $woman_terms_ids ) ) {
            _e('Hello woman', 'woocommerce');
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WordPress function `cat_is_ancestor_of()`.

Check out the docs here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/cat_is_ancestor_of/

Basically, you give it two things: what you think is the parent category and what you expect to be the child category.

No matter how deep the hierarchy goes, it will return true.

Here's a quick example of how you can make it work:

```
$current_category = get_queried_object();
$man_category_id = get_cat_ID('Man');

// Check if the current category or its ancestors include the "Man" category
if (cat_is_ancestor_of($man_category_id, $current_category->term_id)) {
    echo "Display your content here";
}
```

Just a heads up, I haven't tested this code, so feel free to adjust it to fit your situation.